# Photoshop link specific colour with layer mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I have an image on a single layer with various colours and I have several separate *Hue/Saturation* layers with layer masks based on those colours in the image. So for example, charcoal linked to a *Hue/Saturation* layer above it, targeted by a layer mask, then grey with a similar *Hue/Saturation* adjustment layer above it and light grey with the same.

This means the charcoal will have one *Hue/Saturation* alteration, while the grey and light grey will each have completely different *Hue/Saturation* alterations with their own adjustment layer.

This works fine, but if I change any of the colours in the image, the corresponding colour-range-matched *Hue/Saturation* layer will not update itself to match.

I’m guessing this can’t be done. Targeting the colours in the image with a colour range on the *Hue/Saturation* layer won’t work either since the image is greyscale. I need this to work with many different (but similar) images.

I tried using an action even though it’s not ideal, but it didn’t work at all since the colour range selected was fixed – I guess; it isn’t actually doing a colour range based on the colours of the image being used. Very odd.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It might help if you [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/140165/edit) and post some images  to show what you are actually trying to achieve. Show the starting image and then show what the result should be.  Currently your questions reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Billy Kerr I found some results on here already and they were like this without images just descriptions of the problem, so I thought it was ok. It was the same at the adobe forum, all descriptions no images. Not sure what I would give images of even. You mean a screenshot of the layers?

Comment: I already told you what images to show. "Show the starting image and then show what the result should be."  Without something to see, it's almost impossible to tell from words alone what effect you are actually trying to achieve. Also you are making an assumption that the method your are currently trying to use will work, when in fact it is not working for you. This suggests your entire approach may be the problem.

Comment: @Billy Kerr There's no resulting image per se, I just want the masks to automatically update along with the colours. A starting image would be three shades of grey, and the resulting image would be the same shades of grey with different hues...I don't see how that helps much? It's not a method I'm using that doesn't work, it's a function that seems to not exist...but may do, I just haven't found it.

Comment: That's the problem, a mask cannot update automatically. A mask is just a greyscale image. So the method you think you can use to solve your problem doesn't actually exist.  That's the definition of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Billy Kerr A mask can update automatically if photoshop has that function...you're saying it doesn't...would seem to be the answer to my question. The other option is an action, but you can see above my comment about that at the end of the question....very odd indeed.

Comment: I'd like to help you, but you won't show what you are actually trying to achieve.  All editing jobs have a desired result. I don't really understand your reticence to show what you are trying to achieve. So, I'm finished here.  Good luck.

Comment: @Billy Kerr I already edited my comment above but I think you replied before you saw the new edit. A starting image would be three shades of grey, and the resulting image would be the same three shades of grey with different hues. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I also don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You're saying you have a grey image but then you write '_if I change any of the colours in the image_' — what colors of the grey image..? A psd or screenshots with an example would be more helpful

Comment: @Sergey Kritskiy The colours in the grey image....not technically correct but normally we refer to black, white and grey as colours. All I want to do is update the masks automatically when I paint more of a certain colour in the image.

Comment: I will close this question for now. Please [edit] it to be more clear about what you are trying to achieve, so it can be reopened. A picture is probably the best way, but you could also give us a bunch of HSL colour codes before and after your layer/effect/etc. or similar. In general, please [edit] any additional information into your question. (Also what does “the resulting image would be the same three shades of grey with different hues” even mean? All shades of grey have zero saturation and thus are unaffected by hue.)

Comment: Other users have already spent a lot of effort and have been extremely patient trying to guide you to explain your issue in such a way that we can help you. We do not ask you to show us pictures, previous attempts, and similar to make you jump through some pointless hoop. We do this because our experience with answering such questions tells us that this kind of information is what we lack to properly help you.

Answer (score 1):

A *Gradient Map* might be suitable for your needs (although I don't fully understand your question).

It maps the values from a grayscale image to a color gradient of your choice.

Add the *Gradient Map* as an *Adjustment Layer* and the mapping is dynamically updated as you edit the image. No mask needed.

[image]

Comment: What about the hue saturation layers? I don't see any here? I also don't see how each individual colour is being targeted. I need a separate hue/saturation change to each individual specific colour.

Comment: OK, then I probably misunderstood. As @BillyKerr suggests it would be easier to understand with some screenshots. I just thought that you wanted to color different grayscale values with different colors. With this method you are free to choose any color for the different grayscale values. Just double-click the sliders. No need for Hue/Saturation this way. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: I've updated my question to explain it more. A screenshot wouldn't show anything more since it would be just three shades of grey and then three shades of grey with different hues. I can only describe that I want to target the colours individually specifically so the hue is different, and they update if I paint more of that colour. It's possible your method works, I'm not that familiar with it. With my hue alterations the colour is still grey, but with yours it has become colourised.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to achieve the same thing with gradient map as I can in Hue/Saturation. Like for example, how would I achieve a master hue change of +12 and a saturation change of -60? This is why I just wanted to know how the masks could update with wherever I paint a certain colour.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense to me. If your resulting image really is grayscale it wouldn't make sense to use *Hue/Saturation* as gray tones don't have either. So you must be aiming for a colored result. With the *Gradient Map* solution you don't *need* to use *Hue/Saturation* to change colors. You just choose another color in the gradient. So if you want one of the colors to have +12 hue you enter the corresponding color stop and add 12 to the color's hue. The original image stays in grayscale and can be edited freely.

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't make sense but if I explained everything it gets even more complex, that's why my question was simply 'how do I make masks update automatically'. Yes the greyscale image is just the levels of the image and then various different colour overlays are added on top, like green, blue red etc. Then they have hue/saturation layers on top with FIXED settings. This way if I ever change the base greyscale image, everything updates with all colour versions...it needs to work with all different colours but with a fixed hue/saturation setting..

Comment: @Wolff - The OP is trying to do something (which he refuses to show) and which for some reason he thinks is too complicated to explain to us, but he is trying to fix his failure by trying to implement some imagined functionality that doesn't actually exist. He wants us to be able to make this non-existent functionality work in such a way as to fix his problem. This is the very definition of an XY Problem, and it's exactly why I refused to answer it. Nice answer by the way.

Comment: I would love to help, but i still don't get it. One thing I can say is that you can never have "dynamic" masks that automatically updates, so you need to aim for using some kind of filtering instead and this was an attempt to show you an alternative. A thing you could look into is using *Layer Style > Blending Options > Blend If* on the *Hue/Saturation* layers. Here you can (for any kind of layer) specify which range it's applied in. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/uT5zbUk.gif)

Comment: @Wolff Well yes if you can't have a dynamic masks that automatically update then that is the answer to the question. You do understand it, that's what I wanted to do and you can't do that in photoshop. The only other option was recording an action but photoshop seems to also have a bug with that.

Comment: @Hasen - Exactly where have I made any personal attack on you?  This is utterly preposterous. I've tried to get you to explain your question so that I could help you, but you refuse, and just keep digging the hole deeper.  I really am finished here. And please do NOT make accusations here in future.

Comment: Like @BillyKerr I was also a bit annoyed by the way you ask, but not by you *personally*.  It annoys me because it doesn't seem like a fruitful way to achieve a result. "Can I use method A?", "No.", "Can I use method B?", "No.", "Can I use method C?", "No." ... If you instead asked: "I need to achieve this, what is the best method?", you would get a way better answer. No, you can't automatically update masks in PS, but there are so many other methods of dynamic filtering which might give you the same possibilities. It's not necessarily a "flaw" in PS, but perhaps in your approach?

Comment: Anyway, welcome to GDSE! I hope we haven't scared you off. At least now you've learned that graphic designers *love* screenshots. 

Comment: @Wolff Well it couldn't be asked that way. What I wanted to achieve is just endlessly complex so I simply asked for that one simple thing. It's like when people ask "how do I get an adjustment layer to affect only one layer" and the answer is "use clipping masks". There's no specific overall result, they just want to do that. In this case photoshop DOES have that function. My question is no different to that one but for some reason people are treating me with disrespect.

Comment: @Wolff "I hope we haven't scared you off. At least now you've learned that graphic designers love screenshots." Yes it doesn't seem like the most friendly community. Although I've noticed over time that ALL of stackexchange seem to like for you to either post some code or screenshots. I think it just somehow looks ugly to people if the question is just text and you're guaranteed downvotes. BillyKerr was an extreme example. He so much wanted a screenshot without thinking that a grey image with hues added to it would look the same and wouldn't help at all. You of course realised that.

Comment: @Hasen its not that text is bad. But the problem is that if your text isnt clear and you need to revise the text then you are failing. Atleast here you can discuss it. But on general stackexhange you need to make sure your wuestion is watertight. Anyway the problem here is that this is a XY problem and all people want to be able to give you an alternate solution instead, but your making it unconductive.

Comment: @Wolff Now that you know what it is, do you have any better solutions? If you still don't understand it, then that shows why simply asking if photoshop had that function or not was the only way to go about it.

Comment: I'm sad to hear that you find this community unfriendly. That's not my impression. The way you ask your question and your reluctance to explain and illustrate the wanted result triggers this reaction. @BillyKerr, myself and others with years of Photoshop experience all sense that the method you are using is unnecessarily complicated and that there must be a much simpler way to achieve the wanted result. We've seen this phenomenon ("the XY problem") so many times now. I truly believe everybody just wants to help and just tries to "cut to the chase", which perhaps can be seen as disrespectful.

Comment: Did you look into my suggestion about using *Blend If*?

Comment: @Wolff "The way you ask your question and your reluctance to explain" Seriously? You think I just left and didn't try and explain anything....because all I feel I've been doing is trying to explain it. I've written thousands of words here trying to explain it. I guess it really is an unfriendly community if you think I just said nothing then...

Comment: I said "explain and illustrate *the wanted result*". I don't see anything you said as unfriendly, rude, stupid or anything like that. I just try to focus on the matter we discuss and only say things because I honestly think it will help get closer to a solution. We probably won't get much further with this now ... I truly hope we can put this disagreement behind us and that you won't hesitate to participate on GDSE because of this. Communicating in writing can lead to misunderstandings. I'm sure if we had this conversation face to face it would have been a lot more pleasant. 

Comment: @Wolff I don't know what you mean by illustrate. Only a video with audio would have been better than words. It was difficult to explain the end result which is why I didn't try to initially, I just asked if photoshop had that function or not. Many people ask the same thing here and get no rudeness. Like with the 'how to affect only one layer with an adjustment' - use a clipping mask. No end result explained, just asking about a single function. Although yes, you were not rude, only Billy Kerr. He even came back with the sole purpose to cause more trouble...really don't get people like that.

Comment: @Wolff It's possible the `blend if` may work. It's very fiddly to isolate the colours, if it was a one off it would take much longer than the layer masks. But since I should only need to set it up once it may work better. I'll see how it goes.

Comment: @Wolff `blend if` doesn't work unfortunately because it tries to blend colours within a certain range but as it is one `hue/saturation` layer on top of another, it also blends the colours as they are changed by the `hue/saturation` layers below it....so it has a cumulative effect. The only way seems to be to use layer masks to affect only each specific block of colour in it's location. Actions would be a reasonable method if not for the bug in photoshop...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111595/discussion-between-wolff-and-hasen).

Answer (score 0):

I will answer No, the way you have typed the question a layer can not drive an alpha channel. However, i'm not sure. Why? Because what you are asking for is generally non answerable. In general I can only answer with certainty questions that are in the set of things I know how to do . It awfully hard for me to glean into the set of things I don't know how to do (questions in set "No" are almost always in this set, since i don't know how to do things that can not be done). However in this case i base by assertion on the fact that being able to do this would:

1. Break the core  aim of how transparency is handled in Photoshop. IT would expose a lie that they really would want to perpetuate in name of ease of use.
2. Cannibalize on their other products. A lot of alpha channel tool sets do not trickle down to Photoshop because it would cannibalize on After Effects sales.

This said there is most likely one of 2 nifty workarounds but you didn't ask and have made clear that you are not interested so i wont. (one s blend if mentioned)

Instead i will take you on your action idea. Yeah this can be done you just either need to work with **Image -> Calculations...** or you need to change the foreground color before you do color range selection because it uses that color as the selection regardless of what you recorded. It can also be scripted.

Comment: Yes there is another way to do it, I was just about to post an answer to my own question but now it's been closed so I can't. You seem to be going crazy trying to emphasise that it can't be done in photoshop, no need, photoshop is missing countless functions, many that other drawing applications have and can do no problem. The colour range with actions is a bug in versions earlier than 20.0.7. Surprised nobody picked that up....although perhaps not that surprised considering. I already stated that I tried blend if and it didn't work...

Comment: @Hasen im not apologizing anything im just elborating that i can not answer things that have NO as a answer you can only infere therefpre i have to bas emy no on something. But this is more about you wanting a indirect modeler and photoshop being a direct modeller instead. Anyway i dont actually think photoshop is a good software for general pixel pushing, its just a good software for digital print perparation. Its really a medicore if not bad pixel manipulator, its medicore paintinig app, its a medicore image adjustment application, its really bad at keying etc.

Comment: "i can not answer things that have NO as a answer"....no idea what that means. Anyway, I think somehow everyone got so hung up on wanting to know what I wanted to achieve that they A. didn't realise this was just a simple question like "how do I save to png?" or "how do I reverse a layer mask?" etc...if you can't do it in photoshop, then you just say that...and b. nobody noticed that the actions option in my question, was not working for me due to a bug not present in a later version....literally anyone with any photoshop knowledge could have checked that and solved the problem...

Comment: @Hansen its not simple at all. I can only prove things true. This is why science can not disprove existence of god. For same reason I can not prove that photoshop can not do it because to do so i would need to know everything about photoshop. Since i dont i can only guess that photoshop can not do it. This makes it nearly impossible to get people to say you can not do it. No matter how trivial the question in Q and A  most people wont answer it. Which is what counts. This is why everybody wants to modify your question into a form they can answer.

Comment: "This makes it nearly impossible to get people to say you can not do it." Lol, several people said it already in the comments above several times...it's very easy indeed to say that photoshop can't do it, but people seem to find it difficult to admit it for some strange reason...but a few people did after a while...people would rather try to change your question into something completely different rather than admit it's a feature missing from photoshop. Without this weird human behaviour they would have noticed the actions bug and solved the problem very quickly.

Comment: It's very simple indeed - "can you make masks update automatically in photoshop - no". People just tried to make it complex by trying to change the question as you say. They made a simple question complex. If photoshop DID have this function, they'd just say 'yeah you do this and this...' and that would be the end of it. But since it doesn't we have the strange phenomenon I described above.

Comment: Umm yes but how do you distinguish that from some info that is only known by a few userds?

Comment: Distinguish what?

Comment: How do you distinguish between no answer for not possible, not interesting and very few people know @Hasen

Comment: That's an absolutely ridiculous statement - every stackexchange must be absolutely FULL of questions where the answer is "it's not possible"....sorry but you live in some kind of dream world where every piece of software is totally infallible....not to mention that the people asking the questions obviously don't know if what they're asking is possible before they ask it otherwise....they wouldn't ask it lol....Also you can't distinguish between ONE thing so still not sure what you want to distinguish between either...

Comment: @Hasen but even here its a lie of sorts. Nothing stops me from compiling a channel swapper plugin and suddenly its possible to do what you ask. Its just a question of how far your willing to go.

Comment: That's not a lie at all, stackexchange is still full of questions where the answer is "it's not possible", and so it's perfectly reasonable to give that as an answer - no matter how far you're willing to go. If you DO have a solution then by all means give one. Sometimes it's either not possible or not practical. Of course you can build something yourself but that's not really a function that the software has...